# Dynamic Table: Link button to textbox cell by cell

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a dynamic table, where, on every row I have a text box (txtCantitate) and a button (btnMinus). In the textbox I have quantity (int) and on the button click I want the quantity to decrease by one. Here you have what I have on the table:

Can you help me make the code for the buttons? The problem is that it is a dynamic button... on every record it has the same ID... I don't know how to do it...

My languages used on the project C#, .NET 4.5, js, Jquery.

```
cell = new HtmlTableCell();
HtmlInputButton btnMinus = new HtmlInputButton();
btnMinus.ID = "btnMinus";
btnMinus.Value = "-";
cell.Controls.Add(btnMinus);
row.Cells.Add(cell);

cell = new HtmlTableCell();
HtmlInputText txtCantitate = new HtmlInputText();
txtCantitate.ID = "txtCantitate";
txtCantitate.Value = publicatie.Cantitate.ToString();
cell.Controls.Add(txtCantitate);
row.Cells.Add(cell);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a click event on the button, which will perform the action you want:

You will need to set the ID of both the textbox and the button to match the row+cell index you're in first... since these are HtmlControls, you don't really have their index so you'll have to find a way to get these in there somehow (i won't code this for you, sorry).

```
btnMinus.ID = "btnMinus_" + CurrentRowIndex.ToString() + "_" + CurrentCellIndex.ToString();
txtCantitate.ID = "txtCantitate_" + CurrentRowIndex.ToString() + "_" + CurrentCellIndex.ToString();
```

then you will have to set the event handler...

server side click event handler setter (see below for actual event handler code):

```
btnMinus.Click += myButtonClick;
```

client-side click event handler setter:

```
btnMinus.Attributes.Add("onclick","JavaScript:myButtonClick(this);");
```

If you want to do the event handler code server-side:

```
private void myButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button tmp = sender as Button;
   string[] id = tmp.ID.Split(new string[]{"_"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
   string textbox_ID = "txtCantitate" + "_" + id[1] + "_" + id[2];
   TextBox txt = this.Controls.FindControl(textbox_ID) as TextBox;
   int val = -1;
   string finaltext = "";
   if(int.TryParse(txt.Text, out val))
      finaltext = (val-1).ToString();
   else
      finaltext = "Invalid number, Cannot decrement!";

   txt.Text = finaltext;
}
```

If you want to do the event handler code client-side:

```
function myButtonClick(object sender)
{
   //i'll let you figure this one out for yourself if you want to do it client-side, but it's very similar to the server-side one as far as logic is concerned... 
}
```

Comment: I would like to use the server side aproach, but the "sender.ID.Split(new string[] { "_" }, StringSplitOptions.None);" is not working, it's not recognising the ID ... and Ideeas?

Comment: Check the code changes I just posted in my solution... you should try to play around with it... might be Id instead of ID... etc

Comment: The id is parseing ok, forgot to post... but now I have another problem...  the FindControl is not recognised it always comes null; I tried:

TextBox txt = this.Controls.FindControl(id) as TextBox;
Control con = FindControl(id);
TextBox txt = FindControl(id) as TextBox;
HtmlInputText txt = (HtmlInputText)FindControl(id);

and nothing...

Comment: I have a masterpage called "MeniulPrincipal.Master" and the table is called "listaProduse" that is in a div, that in in a contentplaceholder called "ContentPlaceHolderContinut" ... I searched for a solution for... 3 hours and nothing...

Comment: Finally found the solution... I had to call the table first: HtmlInputText txtBox = (HtmlInputText)listaProduse.FindControl(id);

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Ok didn't know that... yes, dynamic controls need to be referenced by their naming containers... happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution,

**Javascript**

```
function MinusVal(ctrl)
{
    var TextBox = $(ctrl).parent().next().find("input[type=text]");
    var Value = parseInt(TextBox.val());

    TextBox.val(Value - 1);
    return false;
}
```

**C# Backend**

```
btnMinus.Attributes.Add("onclick", "MinusVal(this);");
```